Unable to create menu with toolbar using Viewpager2 (without fragments)
When I try to create the menu via "onCreateOptionsMenu" on my Viewpager2 (without fragments) toolbar, the menu is not being created. I can only see the toolbar without a menu. When I use an ActionBar Apptheme I am able to create the menu, but when I use a NoActionBar AppTheme the menu isin't working. I want to use the toolbar instead of the actionbar, but I'm unable to proceed without the menu. Any ideas?
Toolbar without Menu:

Menu:

Expected result after onCreateOptionsMenu:


class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var viewPager2: ViewPager2

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)

        val sports: Sports = intent.getParcelableExtra("Intent to Detail Activity")!!
        val sportsList: List<Sports> = Sports.sportsList(applicationContext)

        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.detail_view_pager)
        viewPager2.setPageTransformer(ZoomOutPageTransformer())

        val viewPagerAdapter = DetailViewPagerAdapter(sportsList, this, viewPager2)
        viewPager2.adapter = viewPagerAdapter
        viewPager2.setCurrentItem(sports.id, false)
    }

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menu.clear()
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    return true
  }
}


    class DetailViewPagerAdapter(
    private val sportsList: List<Sports>,
    private val activity: Activity,
    private val viewPager2: ViewPager2
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailViewHolder>() {

    class DetailViewHolder(
        itemView: View
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val toolbar: Toolbar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar)
        private val banner: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detail_image_view)
        private val title: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_detail_text_view)
        private val subtitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle_detail_text_view)
        private val about: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.about_detail_text_view)

        fun bind(
            sport: Sports
        ) {
            banner.setImageResource(sport.banner)
            title.text = sport.title
            subtitle.text = sport.subtitle
            about.text = sport.about
           // toolbar.title = sport.title
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DetailViewHolder {
        return DetailViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_detail_adapter, parent, false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DetailViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val sportsArgs: Sports = sportsList[position]
        holder.bind(sportsArgs)

        holder.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            activity.finish()
        }
 }
    override fun getItemCount() = sportsList.size
} 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/detail_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>     

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".view.detail.DetailActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/detail_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:liftOnScroll="true"
        app:liftOnScrollTargetViewId="@id/detail_view_scroll_view">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_up_button"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Toolbar.DetailTitle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
             />



    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/detail_view_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/detail_image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_hockey" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtitle_detail_text_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorSecondaryVariant"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/detail_image_view"
                tools:text="Subtitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_detail_text_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline4"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subtitle_detail_text_view"
                tools:text="Title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/about_detail_text_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_detail_text_view"
                tools:text="@string/about_tennis" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:rippleColor="?attr/colorOnSecondary" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

